# Обоснование для запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Снова к вам за помощью. Вот такое предложение попалось:

*На рубашку и пояс с кошелём только посмотрел — сил нагибаться за ними, потом тянуть на себя никчемную ткань и кусок кожи, совершенно не было.*

Как-то мне не нравится запятая после "кожи", подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли она тут и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***На рубашку и пояс с кошелём только посмотрел — сил нагибаться за ними, потом тянуть на себя никчемную ткань и кусок кожи //совершенно не было.***

Чтобы объяснить постановку или отсутствие запятой, надо выполнить **грамматический разбор** предложения.

1) Это БСП, состоит из двух предложений, второе предложение имеет пояснительное значение в добавочном сообщении.

2) Второе предложение безличное (отрицательно-бытийное), в нем выражается отсутствие чего-либо (сущ. в Р.п. является семантическим субъектом): ***не было сил.***

3) Далее разбираем сочетание: ***совершенно не было сил (каких?) нагибаться, потом тянуть.*** Это **однородные несогласованные определения**, выраженные инфинитивом; порядок слов нормальный.

3) Далее переходим к инверсии: ***сил нагибаться, потом тянуть совершенно не было.***

4) **Инверсия** связана с актуальным членением предложения: предмет (о чем говорим) — сообщение (что говорим).

Произносительная (не грамматическая пауза) делается на месте перелома интонации, **запятой такая пауза не обозначается.**

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидала!

Answer (score 3):

*Сил нагибаться, потом тянуть совершенно не было.* Запятая, естественно, не нужна.

Comment: Кого прикажете цитировать, господа модераторы и их добровольные помощники?

Comment: Неужели Niemand такой злостный нарушитель правил сайта? Я вроде бы каждый день просматриваю вопросы, но ничего оскорбительного с его стороны не заметил. Не устраивает ответ - ставьте минус. Не нравится участник - не замечайте его.

Comment: Да, интересная история (и грустная даже для меня). Автор ответа ведь был в полшаге от истины. В приведенном им варианте (а это основная часть предложения) запятая отсутствует ОЧЕВИДНО. Надо было только дополнительно указать грамматическую роль инфинитивов как однородных определений. Цитировать же действительно нечего, одна грамматика в чистом виде.

Comment: так в теоретическом обосновании все и дело - я и сама чувствую, что запятая тут не к месту, но вот аргументировать не могу, и это меня нервирует. Поэтому +50 "не за удар молотком, а за знание, куда ударить".

Answer (score 0):

Основа предложения: `Сил нагибаться совершенно не было`. Запятые отделяют уточнающую конструкцию от основного предложения. А вообще, предложение звучало бы странно без союза.

`Сил нагибаться и потом тянуть совершенно не было.` Не нужно запятой. Это одно безличное предложение.

`Сил нагибаться, а потом тянуть, совершенно не было.`  Безличное предложение отделено запятыми.